# Question about possible frequencies in a closed pipe

Tags: waves, acoustics

Apparently the formula that expresses the possible frequencies in a closed pipes is the following:

$$f = (2n+1)\frac{v}{4L}$$

Where $n=0, 1, 2, 3, ...$, $v=$ the speed of sound and $L=\frac{\lambda}{4}$ (divided by 4, for some unknown reason)

On the flipside you have the following formula for open pipes:

$$f = n\frac{v}{2L}$$

where $n=1, 2, 3, ...$

Unfortunately I don't understand *why* exactly those formula express the possible frequencies. How were they constructed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diagram usually helps:

[image]

This shows (bottom to top) a pipe that is open at the right, the displacement amplitude of the fundamental waveform (node at the closed end, antinode at the open end), and the first harmonic. You can see that the length of the pipe corresponds to 1/4 wavelength, 3/4 wavelength, etc.

You can make that into an equation: $$L = \frac{(1+2n)\lambda}{4}$$

Knowing the relationship between wavelength, frequency and speed of sound, you should be able to transform that into the expression you had.

For a closed-at-both-ends pipe, the longest wavelength will be given from $L = \lambda/2$, and the next ones are $L=\lambda$, $L=\frac32 \lambda$, etc. Again, a little manipulation will get you to the expression you had.

Comment: The pattern is true because a node must exist at a closed end of the pipe, and an antinode must exist at an open end of the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the rules of a pipe:

(1) At "closed ends", the wave amplitude must be zero.

(2) At "open ends", the wave amplitude must be at it's maximum or minimum.

Now draw your pipe, and then draw a sine wave (which starts at amplitude 0) with as long a wavelength as possible while still satisfying these to conditions.

Comment: well that is exactly what I tried... But unfortunately this didn't really clarify the formula's to me.

Comment: @ghyu When you draw the sine waves, you will seen that you cannot chose arbitrary wavelengths if you comply the conditions (1) and (2) above. Those possible wavelengths will be in an arithmetic progression 1/1, 1/3, 1/5... Can you find them? Where are you stuck?